# How to get what selected Select is click

Tags: php, ajax

I have multiple drop down box, it is a result on a loop.

```
foreach($Transs as $Trans){
<select data-id="'.$Trans->coursetitle.'" name = "Schedule" id = "Schedule" class = "form-control" '.$disabled.'>
<option></option>
</select>
}
```

Everytime i want to click a select box, it will populate a data from php and display as option in the clicked box.

Here my ajax

```
<script>

$(document).on("click", "#Schedule", function () {
    var subid = $(this).data('id');
    var dataString = 'id=' + subid;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../class/formschedule.class.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var len = data.length;
            $("#Schedule").empty();
            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                var id = data[i]['id'];
                var name = data[i]['name'];

                $("#Schedule").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But what happens is that only the first drop down box is populated not what i clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Page must contain unique id. You are giving same id to multiple select that's why only first id event done. Change your id to class then perform action

```
foreach($Transs as $Trans){
echo '<select data-id="'.$Trans->coursetitle.'" name = "Schedule" class = "form-control Schedule" '.$disabled.'>
<option></option>
</select>';
}
```

Ajax:

```
<script>

$(document).on("click", ".Schedule", function () {
    var subid = $(this).data('id');
    var dataString = 'id=' + subid;
    var attr = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../class/formschedule.class.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var len = data.length;
            $(attr).empty();
            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                var id = data[i]['id'];
                var name = data[i]['name'];

                $(attr).append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what issue are you getting?

Comment: it wont populate the dropdown

Comment: Have added class? And properly done changes of ajax?

Comment: Will you try my edited answer? I have updated ajax code

Comment: i tried your edited answer. it worksss... but looking at the code, what is the difference of putting the $this to a variable?.. but thanks very much

Comment: After ajax event in success function it will be the object of ajax event so